# Converting a code from Stata to R (event study)

Tags: r, stata, panel-data

I am working with panel data, where my two dimentsions are **exporter_importer** and **year**.
I was wondering if anyone is able to translate the following code from Stata to R?

```
bys exporter_importer (year):egen event_year = min(cond(event,year,.))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackover flow. It would probably help if you were explicit about what your expected output for this STATA code is - not all users of R will be familiar with STATA code. It would also help if you included a minimal dataset. These links may help to make the most of asking a question on SO [ask] and [mre]

Comment: You're often much better off explaining what you want to calculate in R than in showing other code, here Stata code. The number of people who are very fluent in R much exceeds the number of people very fluent in R and Stata. No disrespect to Stata, as my profile implies, but a direct R question is far more likely to get a good answer quickly. So show what your data look like in R and then explain in words what you want to calculate. But at least try some R code. Questions with no attempt at code often are ignored, to say no more.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:** Significantly improved version thanks to Mike and Nick Cox (and remembering Peters comment to share data and desired output):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% arrange(exporter_importer, year) %>% 
       group_by(exporter_importer, year) %>%
       mutate(event_year = ifelse(event==1,min(year),NA))
       ungroup() # optional
```

---

Original answer:

Not a Stata expert (especially not knowing about "cond") but my guess is that you are maybe looking for something along those lines:

```
df %>% 
library(dplyr)
group_by(exporter_importer, year) %>%
mutate(event_year = min((if.else(event,year,.)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Comment: @Maganius, I completely agree that it is difficult to figure out what is being asked here, especially because `min` is being combined with `cond`. Btw, `cond` in Stata is essentially the R equivalent of `if_else` but with more functionality. This [journal article](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0500500310) provides more information.

Comment: @Mike is correct. `min(cond(event, year, .))` finds the minimum (i.e. first) year for which a variable `event` is true. In Stata, true means numeric and not zero: conventionally, but not necessarily, `event` would be coded 1 if true and 0 if false. So the code says, informally translated: for distinct exporter, importer pairs, return the first year in which there was an event. The bare period (stop, dot) is Stata's system missing, which would be ignored by `min()` to the extent possible.

Comment: I have to agree that this is a tough question without an explicit data example.

Comment: @Magasinus, as @Nick Cox's very helpful response indicates, `.` is the equivalent of `NA` in R. Additionally, @Nick Cox's suggestion of coding `event` as a dummy variable helps us come up with a workable answer. Because you are new to the forum, I want you to get credit. Accordingly, kindly add `library(tidyverse)` above your code, and I'd suggest that you update your answer as follows: `df %>% arrange(exporter_importer, year) %>% group_by(exporter_importer, year) %>%
    mutate(event_year = ifelse(event==1,min(year),NA))`